# group.get_all_permissions() in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-guardian

Is there a such thing as `user.get_all_permissions()` for groups? I need a list of all of the group's permissions so that I can find names to reference these same permissions later.

Comment: `group.permissions` which is not what you wanted?

Comment: That's the one. Thanks, for whatever reason I was struggling to find that. `group.permissions.all()`